# Calling method from a class to a window

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I got one window in which there is a button and big text block, and the class in which I got a public method which sets the text to the text block in the window. The problem is, that this doesn't work and I quite don't understand why. The code looks like this:

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
  private void GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Watcher watcher = new Watcher();
        watcher.StoryMode();
    }
```

And here is the public void StoryMode from class Watcher:

```
    string text1 = @"C:/Users/Desktop/Folder/1.txt";
    string mainText;
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

    public void StoryMode()
    {
            mainText = text1;
            mw.textBlock_story.Text = File.ReadAllText(mainText);
    }
```

Every time when I click on the button, nothing happen and when I try to debug, I can see that it calls the function from the Watch class, but doesn't do anything at all. When I tried same code, but outside the Watch class, inside the MainWindow like this :

```
    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text1 = @"C:/Users/Desktop/Folder/1.txt";
        string mainText;
        mainText = text1;
        textBlock_story.Text = File.ReadAllText(mainText);
    }
```

All works fine, but I that's not exactly something what I want in this case.

Could somebody explain me why does this happen and how to get a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried making watcher a member of your MainWindow and initialize it like this: watcher = new Watcher(); in MainWindow's constructor for instance?

Comment: MainWindow is a new instance of the window, if you expect to change current displayed window content then it won't happen. If you want to show a new window then donìt forget to call Show(). And...well...you should actually have a ViewModel not a...separate class which populate UI controls content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your window class needs to create an instance of the watcher class. It should then extract the text data from the watcher class.

```
 class Watcher
{
    public string mainText;
    void StoryMode()
    {
        mainText = "Example Text";
    }

}

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string texblock_story_text;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    void Get_Text()
    {
        Watcher MyWatcher = new Watcher();
        texblock_story_text = MyWatcher.mainText;
    }


}
```